# How to create a Partitioned / Clustered Table in Snowflake Using Snowpark

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowpark python api one is able to create a table by

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("my_table")
```

But , how do we provide options like on which column the table should be clustered on ?

In Pyspark this can be achieved by providing the `partitionBy` / `ClusterBy` option

```
df.write
  .partitionBy("month")
  .clusterBy(50, "id")
  .saveAsTable("myTable")
```

Is this even possible in snowpark?

Comment: Simply run the sql after writing to table.

ALTER TABLE <name> CLUSTER BY ( <expr1> [ , <expr2> ... ] )

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is coming in version 1.8.0 (see this [commit](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/commit/590e34a01b843e0a63710519bd262c2a21cf06cc)). It works as follows:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("my_table", clustering_keys=["id"])
```